# About distance of a point from a set and existence of a convergent sequence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Consider  a subset D  of a normed space X. Let y  is a vector in X . we find the distance of y from D by finding the distance of y from every point of D and take infimum of it and it comes out to be £> O. Then i read in my book that by the definition of infimum  there exist a sequence in D which converge to £ . now my question is how it formed and converge to £ .  Now I start arrange the vectors in D in decreasing order(in terms of their distance from y) to form a sequence. I thing ultimately it approaches to £ . but i am unable to prove mathematically how it converge to £.  Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you consider that, by definition :

$$\mathcal{L}(x)=\inf\{\Vert x-d\Vert\,;d\in D\}$$

you should notice that :

- in general, $\mathcal{L}(x)\ge0$ (it can be zero ... or not)
- there does *not* necessary exist $d_0\in d$ such that $\mathcal{L}(x)=\Vert x-d_0\Vert$.

Now, be definition of an infimum, we know that for every $\epsilon>0$, the number $\mathcal{L}(x)+\epsilon$ is *not* a lower bound of the set $\{\Vert x-d\Vert;\,d\in D\}$, which means that there exists $d\in D$ such that $\Vert x-d\Vert<\mathcal{L}(x)+\epsilon$.

So, by choosing $\epsilon=\frac1n$ ($n\ge1$), we construct a sequence $(d_n)$ of elements of $D$ such that :

$$\forall n\ge1,\,\mathcal{L}(x)\le\Vert x-d_n\Vert<\mathcal{L}(x)+\frac1n$$

This implies that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\Vert x-d_n\Vert=\mathcal{L}(x)}$